# Создать метод для изменения данных в Inner Class

Tags: java

Пытаюсь сделать метод, который добавляет деньги в Storage, и также отнимает.
Тоесть по логике ведь, когда клиент кладет деньги в банк, общая сумма в банке увеличивается, а когда клиент снимает деньги - уменьшается(withdraw типа), но как это решить? Вот что я имею и пытаюсь написать методы:

```java
  @Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Bank {

    private String name;
    private Storage storage;
    private List<Client> clients;

    public Bank(String name, List<Client> clients) {
        this.clients.addAll(clients);
        this.name = name;
        this.storage = new Storage(5000000000L);
    }

    public Bank(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.clients = new ArrayList<>();
        this.storage = new Storage(5000000000L);
    }

    public void addAllClientsToBank(Client... clients) {
        this.clients.addAll(Arrays.asList(clients));
    }
    // Не меняет Storage:(
    public Long putMoneyOfClient(Client client){
        Long clientMoney = client.getMoney();
        Long storageMoney = storage.getMoney();
        return clientMoney + storageMoney;
    }

    //Inner Class Storage of money
    @Getter
    @Setter
    static class Storage {
        private Long money;

        private Storage(Long money) {
            this.money = money;
        }

        // Dont know if its usefull
        public Long AddMoneyToStorage(Long summ) {
            Long result = getMoney();
            result += summ;
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Storage: In this bank" + "(" + money + " $" +
                    ')';
        }
    }
}
```

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Client extends Person {

    private String telephoneNumber;
    private Long money;

    public Client(String firstName, String lastName, int age, String telephoneNumber, Long money) {
        super(firstName, lastName, age);
        this.telephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
        this.money = money;
    }
}
```

**решение**
изменил метод класса Storage

```java
public void AddMoneyToStorage(Long summ) {
            this.money += summ;
        }
```

и метод класса Bank

```java
public void putMoneyOfClient(Client client){
        Long clientMoney = client.getMoney();
        storage.AddMoneyToStorage(clientMoney);
    }
```

Comment: Решил проблему, извиняюсь

Comment: При вызове `Bank(String name, List<Client> clients)` вылетит `NPE`, потому что `this.clients` не проинициализирован.

Comment: Тогда удалите вопрос или ответьте на него сами.

Comment: Как отвечать конкретному пользователю, например вам, чтоб вы видели, что я вам пишу?

Почему будет NPE?  В любом случае, я пользуюсь вторым конструктором.

Comment: В первом конструкторе у списка `client` вызывается метод, но список не был инициализирован (`= new ArrayList<>()`), поэтому выбросится `NPE`. Можно через @(имя пользователя), но в данном случае мне уведомление пришло.

Comment: @ekstra777 не забудьте при добавлении на счет что сумма добавляемых денег должно быть не меньше нуля. то же с отниманием =)

Comment: @ИмяФамилия да я это понимаю) , я просто не использовал этот первый вариант. но мог бы создавая в main List. :)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ 
 да я уже сделал адекватную логику и с снятием денег и добавлением, и аккаунт добавил, и еще не знаю что можно добавить)
Еще бы найти идейки реализаций кроме банка. А то я уже несколько месяцев учу спринг, а до сих пор мало практики completed реализаций ООП хотябы на консоли